# How to get all the gesture recognizers attached to a view using LLDB in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, lldb

I am using Xcode 8 beta 4 and Swift 3. I want to use LLDB to check if a gesture recognizer is added/ working for an element in a view controller.

How to do that using LLDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite simple: you need to find the address of view in Object Inspector (if I understand correctly, you want to use view hierarchy debugger):
[image]
 create a variable with this address in lldb and ask gesture recognizer property from it:

```
(lldb) e UIView* $view = (UIView*) 0x10bd11cf0
(lldb) po [$view gestureRecognizers]
<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x170015f20>(
<UIGestureRecognizer: 0x174167200; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x10bd11cf0>; target= <(action=gestureChanged:, target=<TestFacebookSDK.ViewController 0x100c0d6f0>)>>
)
```